# Lazarus Pascal / Delphi - Error connecting to database

Tags: database, postgresql-9.1, freepascal, lazarus, fpc

I'm trying to connect to my postgresql database using Lazarus pascal. I get this error towards the end of compilation (F9).

> mainform.pas(112,35) Error: Wrong number of parameters specified for
>   call to "Create"

Here's my code:

```
  dbConn:= TSQLConnection.Create(nil);    
  dbConn.HostName := '<IP goes here>';    
  dbConn.DatabaseName:= 'dbMydb';    
  dbconn.UserName:='me';    
  dbConn.Password:='pas';    
  dbConn.Open;

  //Bind the Transaction AND Query components to the DB connection

  dbQuery_Menu := TSQLQuery.Create; //This is the line with the error    
  dbQuery_Menu.Database := dbConn;    
  dbQuery_Menu.Transaction := dbTrans ;
```

I'm really exhausted trying to figure this out... Any help please...

The above code was adapted [from here](http://wiki.freepascal.org/SqlDBHowto).

Comment: For those who bump into the same issue or would like to fix this, here's the code: http://pastebin.com/RSBkusDM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems which the [documentation](http://wiki.freepascal.org/SqlDBHowto) is outdated, the `TSQLQuery` descends from the `TCustomSQLQuery` class where the constructor is defined like

```
 constructor Create(AOwner : TComponent); override;
```

So you need to modify your code like this

```
dbQuery_Menu :=TSQLQuery.Create(nil);
```

Comment: Thank you for your time. Unfortunately, I get the **same** error. Thinking it could be a permissions thing, I even tried this: `dbQuery_Menu.SQL.Text:= 'Select 5+6 as Ans';` but the result is the same. Even tried putting `nil` into all the creates (connection, transaction and query) but nothing seems to change. I'm starting to think it's a bug with Lazarus.

Comment: Are you tell me which you are getting the same error `Wrong number of parameters specified for call to "Create"` after of modify the code with me suggested code?

Comment: Oh no, I'm so sorry for any cofusion... The past few days has been hectic and I've got more lost than ever before... I'm able to run it like you said either putting `nil` or the name of a component on the form. But now it crashes when the query opens.

Comment: Sorry about that confusion... For this question, I accept your answer.  But I just can't get the code to open the query. BTW, am doing it all through code - not using the components on the top tab.

Comment: here is the other question - it's where the program crashes when the query is being opened. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13138271/lazarus-free-pascal-delphi-runerror-211#comment17873017_13138271