# Lazarus Free Pascal / Delphi - RunError 211

Tags: delphi, postgresql, runtime-error, freepascal, lazarus

I'm trying to connect my Windows XP program (Lazarus) to my Ubuntu postgres server.

When the Lazarus program runs, it seems to compile fine but I get this error:

> Project ... raised exception class 'RunError(211)'.

Then it terminates execution (and I don't see any output), and opens up a file **customform.inc**. In that file, it shows a procedure `procedure TCustomForm.DoCreate;` where it highlights a line: `if Assigned(FOnCreate) then FOnCreate(Self);`

I believe this is one of the system's files.

I never get to see any output.
What could this be? Thanks!

MORE INFO:

I've narrowed down the error to this line:

```
  dbQuery_Menu.SQL.Text:='Select * From "tblMenus"';

  dbQuery_Menu.Open;
```

the exception is triggered when the OPEN statement gets executed.

BTW, dbQuery_Menu is defined as a TSQLQuery component.

Clueless! :(

Comment: Is the postgres library properly connected ? Do you use Zeos or other component ?

Comment: @opc0de I am able to successfully connect. But a lot of errors started when I began using the TSQLTransaction component. The whole thing is BTW done via code. No visual components.

Comment: I personally don't have any experience with TSQLTransaction but it works fine for me using zeos component.I suggest you try it if you wont find any solution

Comment: @opc0de Thanks for the tip but I couldn't even install zeos properly. I think the package is missing something or corrupt. Anyway, I'd like to get this working since this is something I hope to port to linux as well.

Comment: If you would like zeos component and a full development IDE to be cross platform i suggest you try [CodeTyphoon](http://www.pilotlogic.com/sitejoom/index.php/codetyphon/codetyphon-about) is lazarus but with all great components.

Comment: @opc0de I've honestly never heard of CodeTyphoon... Maybe I should try it but right now I just need to get this fixed as well :)

Comment: From here - http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/postgresql9/vol2/SQLSTATEvsSQLCODE.html - -211 (ECPG_CONVERT_BOOL)
    This means the host variable is of type bool and the datum in the database is neither 't' nor 'f'. (SQLSTATE 42804)

Comment: also - the SQL 'Select * From "tblMenus"'; it is correct?

Comment: @opc0de I found CodeTyphon on this youtube link (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=82iEb0GPAhs). I think it's just a packager containing Lazarus. I'm not sure but it looks like it. I think it's more like the equivalent of WAMP server. If it's only a packager, I don't think it makes sense for me to install it.

Comment: @itsols it has zeosdb component properly installed

Comment: @RBA +1 for your finding... Yes, I had a boolean field with no value set. But now I've set it. But I still get the error. Same thing. Same place. And another thing - MY error is 211 and your URL pointed to -211. Anyway, it was true. Thanks for your inputs and I hope I get this fixed soon :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After nearly 5 days I found the answer. Many thanks to all thos e ho have contributed with their ideas ESPECIALLY **RRUZ**, **RBA** and **Guillem Vicens**. there are other related posts all connected to getting the FIRST Lazarus program working with PostgreSQL.

Summary.

1. The biggest mistake I made here was that I used the `TSQLConnection` component. Don't do this. Instead use the `TPQConnection`.
2. Everything is done through code. We're not using any draggable components from the top tab.
3. Don't rely on the Lazarus docs (wiki) at least for working with PG DBs.. It is outdated. Some of the examples can be pretty misleading.
4. Make sure that fields have some default values. For example, if a Boolean field has no true or false (t/f) set, this may lead to errors.

And that's it! I hope many postgres+Lazarus newbies will find this useful.

Comment: So it was sort of a combination of what @RRUZ and what I suggested, glad you solved it :-)

Comment: @GuillemVicens Yes, I'm glad that the clouds are really clearing... Actually, I don't understand why the table and field names had to be in quotes. Any way, I'm glad it works :) Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Run error 211 appears when you try to call an abstract method. Check this [link](http://community.freepascal.org:10000/docs-html/user/userch14.html) from more information on FreePascal/Lazarus runtime errors.

Since you say all is done by code and you have no visual components, the problem probably lies in your code trying to use an ancestor component which has not overriden the Open method. You should be able to solve this by using the correct descendant component.

Another possibility, although I would **strongly** recommend to avoid this one, is to override the Open method yourself. It should be avoided because if you are using an ancestor component then you probably would have to override more abstract methods.

HTH

Comment: How would I override something I just created? All I have opened apart from the Query is the Connection :(

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding me. As it seems, your `TSQLQuery` component class has declared `Open` as an abstract method. Abstract methods need to be overriden in descendant classes so they can be used.

Answer (score 1):

From [here](http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/postgresql9/vol2/SQLSTATEvsSQLCODE.html) - http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/postgresql9/vol2/SQLSTATEvsSQLCODE.html - -211 (ECPG_CONVERT_BOOL) This means the host variable is of type bool and the datum in the database is neither 't' nor 'f'. (SQLSTATE 42804)